# Can an Opportunity be Changes with Stage as 'Dropped' or 'Lost' once it is 'Won'

Tags: workflow, opportunity, field-update

I am getting a problem according to which I have two picklist fields in Opportunity: 
1. Stage , 2. Category (Dependent on 'Stage') & 3. Status (text field).

Now I have some workflow's which updates the values of field 'Status' depending upon above mentioned two picklist fields, But the issue is When I give the value of **Stage** field as 'Won' & value in dependent picklist **Category** as 'Closed' my field **Status** is updating correctly and when I update my Opportunity with values in **Stage** field as 'Dropped' & value in dependent picklist **Category** as 'Omit' it will not change my **Status** field to 'Dropped' 

Despite being all the Workflow's having

> Evaluation Criteria = Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it’s edited.

the status field is not updating.

So my concern is, If the Opportunity is being updated as **WON** in any circumstances then is there something like: It prevents the workflow from being triggered *or* It will prevent the Stage status from being updated in back-end depending on which Workflow is not triggering something. 

Aprreciate anybody's help on this.


Thanks!

Chirag

Comment: Have you reviewed the debug log of changing stage to *Dropped*? Can you post it? Are there any validation rules for `status`? Your issue can't be anything serious, but you've provided too little information to understand it well.

Comment: I haven't reviewed the debug-log, I'll do it now if you say so. And there is no Validation Rule on the status field.
Please bear with me till the time I'll review my debug-log.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the CASE function in a formula field to do this without a workflow.

```
CASE(expression, value1, result1, value2, result2,...,else_result)
```

For your example, it would look like the below:

```
  CASE( StageName, 
    "Won", "Win Text", 
    "Dropped", "Dropped Text",
    "")
```